# constexpr C++11 code OK for g++ 4.8.2, but not for latest Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 CTP 2

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, g++4.8

Code with statements such as those shown below compiles fine with g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev4, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.2, but not with the latest [Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 CTP 2 (12.0.306020.00 Update 3 CTP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933779/en-us)

Questions:  Might I be doing something wrong such as not turning on some feature or does the latest Visual Studio 2013 not support such statements?  The code needs to be made to compile under Visual Studio -- any suggestions on how to work around this limitation?

```
namespace NA
{
   namespace NB
   {
      class C1 : P1
      {
         static constexpr double one     = 1.0;
         static constexpr double two     = one + one;
         static constexpr float  a_foo[][2]  =  { { 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 },
                                                  { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 } };

         static constexpr int    n_ele   = 1024;
         static constexpr int    n_d     = 128;
         static constexpr int    n_ape   = n_ele -
                                           n_d  +
                                           1;

         std::vector< std::array< int, (int)n_ele >> ape
         {
            std::vector< std::array< int, (int)n_ele >>
            ( (int)n_ape,  {{0}} )
         };

         std::array<
                      std::array< int,  (int)n_d >,
                      (int)n_ape
                   >  c_to_e = {{ std::array< int, (int)n_d >( {0} ) }};
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you casting all of those `int`s to `int`s?

Comment: Visual Studio's `constexpr` support is limited to weak. The next Visual Studio should include more support. Check out VS2014 CTP (code name 2014). I think it is unlikely that any VS2013 updates with really change the support for VS2013.

Comment: @Casey Short answer: oversight.  Long answer:  project was originally in Matlab wherein members are doubles.  First port to C++ (g++) retained doubles and so needed the cast.  Later revisions identified variables that were actually integral and used integral datatypes for them;  during this stage, some casts were not removed.  All this is still work in progress, and unfortunately needs to be completed in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx), **C++11 `constexpr` is listed as Partial** because VS doesn't support it on member functions.

**C++14 `constexpr`** support is in a separate row with the signification that has **not yet been implemented.**

So I guess, we'll have to wait for newer versions where `constexpr` functionality will be fully implemented.

Comment: What is a "Partial"? Where is it not implemented?

Comment: @BЈовић "C++11 `constexpr` is listed as "Partial" because VS14 CTP1 doesn't support it on member functions."

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ 2013 does not support constexpr at all. You can use "static const" instead of "static constexpr" for Visual C++.